# How to reverse engineer cx_Freeze exe's?

Tags: decompilation, python

How to reverse engineer Python scripts turned into binaries with [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. All questions here are Q&A, thanks for your contribution. No need to point it out with custom "tags", though. I removed the answer from what's formally the question and made cosmetic adjustments to the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks! it wouldnt let me submit the question without that extra text thats why I put it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. find the `library.zip` inside the `lib` folder included
2. extract `EXENAME__main__.pyc` (EXENAME is the name of the exe)
3. run `pip install decompyle3`
4. run `decompyle3 EXENAME__main__.pyc` and the source will be printed onto the screen

Comment: I'm getting xdis might need to be informed about version '3.8.18' and Unknown magic number 3495 or KeyError depending on using decompyle3 or uncompyle6